# Android - call C function without text reallocation in x86 assembler

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, x86, gnu-assembler

Definition of function in gas appends at the end of text section. For example, this defines function `foo`:

```
.text
.globl foo
foo:
   <foo body>
```

All is ok, before you'll want to call C function inside asm function body. Adding `call` instruction (used x86 assembler) leads to `warning: shared library text segment is not shareable` when compiled by Android NDK due to text reallocations (you can compile library with them, but for API less than 23)

I'm not very experienced in assembler, so my question is: can I somehow call C function from asm function without text reallocations? May be I can move function definition in another section (if it possible), or replace `call`?

I'am using x86 assembler and gas syntax

Comment: Try to replace your function call `call foo` with `call foo@PLT`.  This should fix your issues.

Comment: It's works, thank you very much for quick response!

Comment: What are your target devices? (Just curious, as a commercial Android developer I haven't seen many x86 devices, almost none)

Comment: @Ped7g, x86 Android Emulator, because it has best performance on x86 systems (needed due to lack of real devices with particular OS version)

Comment: @VanderDeken Ah so... yeah, the emulator can be x86 (and it's actually quite thin and virtualized well on some setups), so this will work well for you, unfortunately most of my project have to target real devices, so I have to provide also arm versions of code. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @Ped7g There are plenty of Asus tablets which are shipped with x86 and android (like Asus Transformer Pad TF103C)

Comment: @fuz: IDK if Android uses a GOT the same way regular Linux does, but you can also use `call *puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)` for example.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-05/msg00225.html about the `gcc -fno-plt` option that compiles this way instead of using PLT stubs.  (It requires early binding instead of lazy binding, but that may be a good thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fuz's answer (use `call foo@PLT`) is correct, but this solution should be applied only for exported or external functions. Using PLT for local functions (with default visibility) ends with crash, if you call assembler function directly outside librarie's code (because other libraries don't have info about this function in their GOT).

For local functions solution even simpler - just mark them with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`.This allows to compile `call foo` without text relocations.